# bash downloading files ftp url

Tags: bash, curl, ftp

I working with a function to parse a file that has a list of desired file names to download. I'm using curl to download them but is there a better way?  The output is shown which is okay but is there way for the output not be shown?  Is there way to handle exceptions if the file isn't found and move on to the next file to be download if something happens? Might wanna ignore what I do for getting the proper link name, it was pain. The directory pattern has a pattern to what the name of the file is.

```
#!/bin/bash
# reads from the file and assigns to $MYARRAY and download to Downloads/*

FILENAME=$1
DLPATH=$2
VARIABLEDNA="DNA"
index=0

function Download {

VARL=$1
#VARL=$i
echo $VARL
VAR=${VARL,,}
echo $VAR
VAR2=${VAR:1:2}
echo $VAR2
HOST=ftp://ftp.wwpdb.org/pub/pdb/data/structures/divided/pdb/
HOSTCAT=$HOST$VAR2

FILECATB='/pdb'
FILECATE='.ent.gz'
NOSLASH='pdb'
DLADDR=$HOSTCAT$FILECATB$VAR$FILECATE
FILECATNAME=$NOSLASH$VAR$FILECATE
echo $DLADDR

curl -o Downloads/$FILECATNAME $DLADDR

gunzip Downloads/$FILECATNAME


}

mkdir -p Downloads



while read line ; do
        MYARRAY[$index]="$line"
        index=$(($index+1))
done < $FILENAME

echo "MYARRAY is: ${MYARRAY[*]}"
echo "Total pdbs in the file: ${index}"

for i in "${MYARRAY[@]}"
do
    Download $i
done
```

I'm trying to write the log file to a folder that i made before the downloading but it doesn't seem to be making it in the folder. It writes to the root directory of the file that being executed and it doesn't write it correctly either.  My syntax might be wrong??

```
curl -o Downloads/$FILECATNAME $DLADDR >> Downloads\LOGS\$LOGFILE 2>&1
```

Comment: I'm trying to write the log file to a folder that i made before the downloading but it doesn't seem to be making it in the folder. It writes to the root directory of the file that being executed and it doesn't write it correctly either.  My syntax might be wrong??                                                          curl -o Downloads/$FILECATNAME $DLADDR >> Downloads\LOGS\$LOGFILE 2>&1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, first of all, I'm not sure if I got it all right, but I'll give it a try:

- I'm using curl to download them but is there a better way?

I don't know a better one. You could use wget instead of curl, but curl is much more powerful.

- The output is shown which is okay but is there way for the output not be shown?

You could use nohup (e.g. nohup curl -o Downloads/$FILECATNAME $DLADDR). If you don't redirect the output to a specific file, It will be stored in nohup.out. By adding an ampersand (&) at the end of your command you can also let it run in the background, so the command is still executed, even if you loose the connection to the server.

- Is there way to handle exceptions if the file isn't found and move on to the next file to be download if something happens?

You could use something like test...exists.Or you could just check your nohup.out for errors or anything else with a grep.

I hope this helped you in any way.

cheers

Comment: Thanks for you response. I ended up redirected it with this, "curl -o Downloads/$FILECATNAME $DLADDR >> $LOGFILE 2>&1" What do you think?

Comment: As long as everything works as expected, your command does the job.
With nohup you just ignore the HUP (hangup) signal. So it runs in the background and isn't depending on the user anymore which can be useful in some cases. So if you use nohup it still works even wenn for example the SSH connection between the server and your machine is not permanently active.

Comment: I'm trying to write the log file to a folder that i made before the downloading but it doesn't seem to be making it in the folder. It writes to the root directory of the file that being executed and it doesn't write it correctly either.  My syntax might be wrong??                                                          curl -o Downloads/$FILECATNAME $DLADDR >> Downloads\LOGS\$LOGFILE 2>&1

Comment: Okey first yu redirect stdout ">>" to Downloads\LOGS\$LOGFILE and then you redirect stderr to an unspecified file, then appending &1 redirects sderr to stdout

1. thing I would try:
leave the 2>&1 away and see what happens, except you want sterr in your file

2. thing I would try:
- give the full path to the Logfile (without variables)
- replace the parts of the path with the matching variables and see where the problem is